# Is it possible to use Backbone.sync to connect to cometd?

Tags: backbone.js, comet

Is it possible to talk to a cometd service when using Backone.sync?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After some reading it seems you can overwrite the Backbone.sync().

> Backbone.sync is the function that Backbone calls every time it attempts to read or save a model to the server. By default, it uses (jQuery/Zepto).ajax to make a RESTful JSON request. You can override it in order to use a different persistence strategy, such as WebSockets, XML transport, or Local Storage.

I can't find any more information on this though.

Comment: There are a few questions on SO showing how to override `.sync()` - maybe start there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, all you need to do is override `sync`.

A good example to follow in order to see how it is done is the backbone [localstorage storage](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html).

In brief, you define a method that replaces `sync` on your models/collections:

```
mySync = function(method, model, options)
```

The `method` argument can be one of `read`, `create`, `update`, `delete` and `model` can be either a model, or a collection. Essentially you only need to cover the four methods and everything will work like a charm. Bear in mind that while the localstorage example is useful it is also simplistic in some ways, so having a look at Backbone itself never hurts.